# Building larger SOAP requests with javax.xml.soap API by parsing an XML file to a SOAPMessage

Tags: java, xml, soap, request

I have an XML file with a SOAP request which contains about 150+ sentences and I want to send this soap request in my JavaProject via the `javax.xml.soap` API. So normally you build a soap request by using following procedure:

```
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapServiceElem = soapBody.addChildElement("SomeRandomServiceName", "int");
        SOAPElement soapInputMetaDataElem = soapServiceElem.addChildElement("inputMetaData");
        SOAPElement soapVersionElem = soapInputMetaDataElem.addChildElement("version");
        SOAPElement soapVersionText = soapVersionElem.addTextNode("V_1");
        ...
```

and so on.. but this seems a little bit to much if I want to build bigger SOAP requests. Is there another and "better" way to build a SOAP request? Would it be an option to place the XML File as `String` and parse it to a `SOAPMessage` ? Is there something like a build in function to parse a `String` to a `SOAPMessage` or do I have to write an own one?

Or even better: Is it possible to place the request XML file in my project directory and just send this one as soap request? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own class which receives an `FileInputStream` and builds a `soapMessage` out of it:

```
private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(FileInputStream requestFile, String serverURI, String serviceName) throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        MimeHeaders headers = new MimeHeaders();

        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage(headers, requestFile);
        requestFile.close();

        String authorization = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((username+":"+password).getBytes());
        headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + serviceName);
        headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        return soapMessage;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

let us say you have your request in `request.xml`. you can do following:

```
org.w3c.Document document = //read dom from request.xml
soapBody.addDocument(document);
```

for more details see [SoapBody#addDocument(Document)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPBody.html#addDocument(org.w3c.dom.Document))

Comment: But here I get a `org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR` exception. What is in your example `soapBody` and how do you read the dom from the `request.xml`? Should the `request.xml` file contains also a header or just the body, because you add the Document only to the body? I would be very thankful vor some more details on your answer.

Comment: `request.xml` contains only the the part of xml which need to be added inside `soap:body`